# Concatenation in SQL

Tags: mysql

How to concatenate multiple records with the same ID in SQL?

Scenario 1

Concatenate the full value of the first record to the next record with dash(-) and the value after dash in the subsequent record if the the last string equal to the first string example first record US-CA the last string is CA and the subsequent record first string is CA also.

```
ID    Position Desc
123   A11      US-CA
123   A12      CA-UK
123   A13      UK-GE

Result
ID    Position Desc   Concat
123   A11      US-CA  US-CA-UK-GE
123   A12      CA-UK  US-CA-UK-GE
123   A13      UK-GE  US-CA-UK-GE
```

Scenario 2

Concatenate the full value of the first record to the next record with underscore (_) and the value after dash in the subsequent record if the the last string NOT equal to the first string example first record US-CA the last string is CA and the subsequent record first string is FR

```
ID    Position Desc
124   A1      US-CA
124   A2      FR-UK
124   A3      UK-GE

Result 
ID    Position Desc   Concat
124   A1        US-CA  US-CA_FR-UK-GE
124   A2        FR-UK  US-CA_FR-UK-GE
124   A3        UK-GE  US-CA_FR-UK-GE
```

Comment: Tag your question with the RDBMS you're using. "Toad" is a tool, not a database engine.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the correct [tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for your RDBMS

Comment: Hi @Jeroen Mostert, sorry my mistakes just corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: That still lacks a *specific* tag for your engine (e.g. Oracle, MySQL...) "SQL" is a family of dialects. Engines are very different with respect to what kinds of string operations are supported and how those operations are called. They can't even agree on things as basic as the syntax used to concatenate two strings, let alone doing it across rows.

Comment: Does position define first and next? If so what is the format of position. (nchars followed by n integers?)

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon, the position is defined and unique also.

Comment: Not sure if that answers my question, if there is another column which can define first and next please add to your sample if you mean the column already defined as position please clarify format,

Comment: The positon is varchar…

Comment: You seem to be unfamiliar with the problems associated with ordering by varchar and should research that and since you are unwilling to clarify the format of position I'm out.

Comment: Hi P.Salmon, sorry for the confusion, please disregard Position, two columns ID and Desc is enough. Thank you.

Comment: ' two columns ID and Desc is enough' - no it isn't you need to know the order in which the rows occur to get the result you want..nb data is not stored in any particular order..